# Download jar file instead of pom from a remote repository

Tags: java, maven, jar, build.gradle

I created a repository in Github with a jar inside. When I set the dependency on build.gradle file, the only file that is been downloaded is the pom file, but not the jar.

Build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'


configurations {
    cucumberRuntime {
        extendsFrom testRuntime
    }
}

ext {
    seleniumVersion = "2.40.0"
}

eclipse {
        wtp {
            component {
                resource sourcePath: './WebContent', deployPath: '/'
            }
        }
}

configurations {
    cucumberRuntime {
        extendsFrom testRuntime
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://github.com/chrisokamoto/mvn-repo/raw/master/'
    }   
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'snapshots.Aipim4J', name: 'Aipim4J', version: '1.0'
}
```

The repository is on this link: https://github.com/chrisokamoto/mvn-repo/tree/master/snapshots/Aipim4J/Aipim4J/1.0

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps in your URL you have a double "/Aipim4J/Aipim4J/"?

Comment: The URL works... this is not the problem.. it can access the URL.. but the problem is that the project just downloads the pom, and not the jar.. like I want..

Comment: The URL works for me too, just suggesting your dependency compile setting may not resolve to the same URL.  If you would like a full set of debugging information to trace what Maven is doing, you can run the same maven command again with the -X switch.

Comment: I got it! The problem was in the POM file in github. There was an error on groupId